# Re-order an array's items based on several criteria

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

Everybody I asked found this problem too challenging, hopefully there is someone here who can handle it.

I have a program that generates business cards with inputs gave by a user (name, title, address etc.)

I also have a page where users can configure how the info will look on the card: http://screencast.com/t/5j5CKAd0vi2l

Those configurations are used so that if some fields are empty, then other fields can move to take place of the empty field.

How we should expect it to work:
When a "field" is checked, it means that it can move. The arrow indicates the position where it should move. For example, name should move down, and title should move up. So if there is no name given in the input, and there is a title, then the title will go up and take the empty space of the name.

When a field is not checked, it means that it cannot move, and a field cannot take its position (or step over it). So for example if there is a name, but there is no title, then the name would go down to take the title's spot but couldn't go down any further (even if "Office tel" was empty, so there would be a blank space on the business card).

Using the same configurations example, if the user didn't input a mobile and email, but entered the last 2 fields (Address 1 and City, state, zip), then these last 2 fields would go up 2 fields, and take the places of mobile and email.

Let's say my business card inputs are:

```
(checked, pointing down) Name: Dan
(checked, pointing up) Title:
(unchecked) Office tel:
(checked, pointing up) Mobile tel:
(checked, pointing up) Email: grwgwr@geffw.com
(checked, pointing up) Address 1: 12 jal
(checked, pointing up) City, state, zip: NYC, NY, 12345
```

The resulting renderValues array that I need would look like:

```
(
    [0] =>
    [1] => Dan
    [2] => 
    [3] => grwgwr@geffw.com
    [4] => 12 jal
    [5] => NYC, NY, 12345
    [6] =>  
)
```

That's not what I'm getting with my code. You may not need it and it may confuse even more, but here's what I tried putting up so far:

```
foreach ($renderBlocksPropsByOrder as $blockID => $field) {
    $direction = $field['blankSensitivityDirection'];

    // note: if a field is not blank sensitive, it is locked

    if (trim($renderValues[$blockID]) == '' && $field['isBlankSensitive'] == '1') {
        // if ($renderBlocksPropsByOrder[$blockID + 1])
        // the field(s) around this field can take its position
        // ??? if the field above is pointing down and the field below is pointing up, give priority to the field down ???
    } else if (trim($renderValues[$blockID]) == '' && $field['isBlankSensitive'] == '0') {
        // fields above this field cannot go down past it even if it's empty, but they can all go down until they reach it
        // fields below this field cannot go up past it even if it's empty, but they can all go up until they reach it
        // this field will be a "blank" space field
    } else if (trim($renderValues[$blockID]) != '' && $field['isBlankSensitive'] == '0') {
        // similar as the above case, except this field won't be a blank space
    } else if (trim($renderValues[$blockID]) != '' && $field['isBlankSensitive'] == '1') {
        // this field should move if it can
        if ($direction === 'down') {
            // check fields below it to move it to the lowest available spot
            // (fields below have a higher index)
            for ($i = $blockID + 1; $i < $numBlocks; $i++) {
                if (trim($renderValues[$i]) != '') {
                    // prevent stepping over a field that has a value
                    break;
                }
                if (trim($renderValues[$i]) == '' && $renderBlocksPropsByOrder[$i]['isBlankSensitive'] == '1') {
                    $renderValues[$i] = $renderValues[$blockID];
                    $renderValues[$blockID] = ' ';
                    break;
                }
            }
        } else if ($direction === 'up') {
            // check fields above it to move it to the highest available spot
            // (fields above have a lower index)
            for ($i = $blockID - 1; $i >= 0; $i--) {
                if (trim($renderValues[$i]) != '') {
                    // prevent stepping over a field that has a value
                    break;
                }
                if (trim($renderValues[$i]) == '' && $renderBlocksPropsByOrder[$i]['isBlankSensitive'] == '1') {
                    $renderValues[$i] = $renderValues[$blockID];
                    $renderValues[$blockID] = ' ';
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

The array renderBlocksPropsByOrder has the configuration of each field:

```
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [blockID] => 0
        [isBlankSensitive] => 1
        [blankSensitivityDirection] => down
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [blockID] => 1
        [isBlankSensitive] => 1
        [blankSensitivityDirection] => up
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [blockID] => 2
        [isBlankSensitive] => 0
        [blankSensitivityDirection] => ''
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [blockID] => 3
        [isBlankSensitive] => 1
        [blankSensitivityDirection] => up
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [blockID] => 4
        [isBlankSensitive] => 1
        [blankSensitivityDirection] => up
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [blockID] => 5
        [isBlankSensitive] => 1
        [blankSensitivityDirection] => up
    )

[6] => Array
    (
        [blockID] => 6
        [isBlankSensitive] => 1
        [blankSensitivityDirection] => up
    )

)
```

RenderValues has the value of each field. Initial renderValues array looks like:

```
(
    [0] => Dan
    [1] => 
    [2] => 
    [3] => 
    [4] => grwgwr@geffw.com
    [5] => 12 jal
    [6] => NYC, NY, 12345
)
```

I've been spending a long time on this really any help that can help me go forward will be very, very appreciated.

If this way proves to be too complex, I'll take any suggestions for an alternative, user-friendly way of configuring the business cards.

Comment: I clearly don't get these "move up" or "move down" things. If "title" is empty for example, then everything after it moves up ("title" space is removed) and that's it. No? What is the difference with what you want? Or is there any specific reason why you would want to leave blank spaces in your array?

Comment: If title isn't provided and the name is, the name should move down, so that there is no white space. See this generated card is wrong, according to the configuration: http://screencast.com/t/Lo98w9TzXvO2

Comment: I don't know of any algorithm that will sort with blank spaces in the middle.  Php has several different sorting functions built in. http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php

Comment: Blank spaces can be wanted from users in their card. For example they could leave the Email field unchecked, and if email is empty, it would be an empty space. If email was checked and no email was given, then the 2 fields below would go up (and no empty space would be seen)

Comment: I am trying to code something that allows blank spaces in the array. Because then when I create the pdf business card, I am using the empty array fields to add a space in the business card.

Comment: Are you using jquery sortable to move the rows around?

Comment: Can you explain how you come up with `$renderBlocksPropsByOrder` is it directly from a `form` post method? or how?

Comment: @Rasclatt Yes I'm using jQuery sortable to move the rows around - that part works fine.

Comment: @CodeGodie The information is taken from the database. The fields of that array represents the configuration for each row (field) of the business card. Configs that are determined from that form http://screencast.com/t/5j5CKAd0vi2l

Comment: What if mobile and email are empty? Does address take the position of mobile (goes as up as possible), or of email (only one up)?

Comment: @caCtus In this case given this config, up 2 spots. Address would be in mobile's position and "City, state, zip" would be in the position of Email.

Comment: Unless for example address was unchecked, then address and city would stay where they are (as the city, even if checked) wouldnt be able to go up past an unchecked field)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope it solves your problem (found it an interesting case and spent part of the morning on this)

**EDIT:** just re-made the functions and model, so it'll iterate as expected, in order to review the entire model over and over until each slot is sorted out correctly.

```
// Card Model
$card = array (
    1 => array(
        "label"=>"Name",
        "canmove"=>"down",
        "value"=>"Dan"
        ),
    2 => array(
        "label"=>"Title",
        "canmove"=>"up",
        "value"=>""
        ),
    3 => array(
        "label"=>"Office Tel",
        "canmove"=>"n",
        "value"=>""
        ),
    4 => array(
        "label"=>"Mobile Tel",
        "canmove"=>"up",
        "value"=>""
        ),
    5 => array(
        "label"=>"Email",
        "canmove"=>"up",
        "value"=>"grwgwr@geffw.com"
        ),
    6 => array(
        "label"=>"Address 1",
        "canmove"=>"up",
        "value"=>"12 jal"
        ),
    7 => array(
        "label"=>"City, State, Zip",
        "canmove"=>"up",
        "value"=>"NYC, NY, 12345"
        ),
);

// Render it!
$renderedCard = renderCard($card);

// Testing
foreach($renderedCard as $key=>$values) {
    echo "[".$key."] ".$values['label'].": ".$values['value']."<br>";
}

// Structural view
echo "<pre>";
print_r($renderedCard);
echo "</pre>";




// This function nullifies every slot with empty 'value', except if
// its 'canmove' is 'n', which may keep intact
function clearCard($card) {
    $newCard = array();
    foreach ($card as $slot=>$props) {
        $props['value'] != '' || $props['canmove'] == 'n' ?
            $newCard[$slot] = $card[$slot] :
            $newCard[$slot] = null;
    }
    return $newCard;
}

// This function will move each slot to occupy the empty ones, based
// on 'canmove' criteria
function renderCard($card) {
    $cleanCard = clearCard($card);
    $refactor = 0;
    // iterates over cleanCard to perform a 'bubble sort'
    while ($refactor < count($cleanCard)) {
        foreach ($cleanCard as $slot => $props) {
            switch ($props['canmove']) {
                // if 'up', and upward slot is empty,
                // occupy its place and null itself next
                case 'up':
                    // if it overflows the card array offset, breaks
                    if ($slot-1 <= 0) break;
                    // if upper 'value's null, means it can be filled!
                    if ($cleanCard[$slot-1] == null) {
                        $cleanCard[$slot-1] = $cleanCard[$slot];
                        $cleanCard[$slot] = null;
                    }
                    break;
                // same as 'up', but checking downward field
                case 'down':
                    if ($slot+1 > count($cleanCard)) break;
                    if ($cleanCard[$slot+1] == null) {
                        $cleanCard[$slot+1] = $cleanCard[$slot];
                        $cleanCard[$slot] = null;
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
        // increment the refactor to loop while over cleanCard count
        $refactor++;
    }
    // when finished, returns the rendered array
    return $cleanCard;
}
```

**OUTPUTS**

*1) Following the model on your question:*

```
[1] :
[2] Name: Dan
[3] Office Tel:
[4] Email: grwgwr@geffw.com
[5] Address 1: 12 jal
[6] City, State, Zip: NYC, NY, 12345
[7] :
```

*2) Adding a "Title" (CEO):*

```
[1] Name: Dan
[2] Title: CEO
[3] Office Tel:
[4] Email: grwgwr@geffw.com
[5] Address 1: 12 jal
[6] City, State, Zip: NYC, NY, 12345
[7] :
```

*3) And now, a "Mobile Phone" as well:*

```
[1] Name: Dan
[2] Title: CEO
[3] Office Tel:
[4] Mobile Tel: 55559999
[5] Email: grwgwr@geffw.com
[6] Address 1: 12 jal
[7] City, State, Zip: NYC, NY, 12345
```

*4) What if you have a "Title" but not a "Name"? Let's see:*

```
[1] Title: CEO
[2] :
[3] Office Tel:
[4] Email: grwgwr@geffw.com
[5] Address 1: 12 jal
[6] City, State, Zip: NYC, NY, 12345
[7] :
```

*5) Let's remove the "Address 1" now, so "City, State, Zip" should take its place:*

```
[1] Title: CEO
[2] :
[3] Office Tel:
[4] Email: grwgwr@geffw.com
[5] City, State, Zip: NYC, NY, 12345
[6] :
[7] :
```

*6) [EDIT] Setting 'Email' field as `canmove` 'down', as well 'Address 1' and 'City, State, Zip' with empty values, so Email should move all its way down!:*

```
[1] Title: CEO
[2] :
[3] Office Tel:
[4] :
[5] :
[6] :
[7] Email: grwgwr@geffw.com
```

Feel free to perform other tests and give a feedback, I had a great time doing this!

(Remove the former **EDIT** of the previous answer regarding issues on index and notices, since it isn't the case anymore)

Comment: Best solution to avoid Notices is not `error_reporting(~E_NOTICE);`, but fixing the notice. (Test index' existence here.) Plus "some tests I made didn't pass" => Would have been good to tell which of them, to help OP. :)

Comment: Agreed, but like I said, "not a definitive solution; may be a good starting point", something to work on. He'll going to make modifications since his data comes through a different array structure. Anyway, the failing tests were a little pushed up, like forcing the stack to switch elements when everyone with odd index got 'canmove' deny. Some of the fields gone missing! But I assume that won't be the case since this situation doesn't fit the described scenario.

Comment: Hi, thanks for that, I'm trying to make it work. In your example the title has no value and goes to the top, and if the title has a value as well, the title also goes to the top (shows before the Name which isn't intended).

Comment: Thank you for the input, I'll try to fix that!

Comment: Also, let's say that Email is empty, then the fields "Address 1" and "City, state, zip" would move up 2 fields (2 because then it reaches "Office Tel" which isn't an available spot). The code seems to move things only by 1 space even if 2 or more spaces are available. I'm trying to figure out fixes as well I'll update if I find something.

Comment: ok I fixed a couple issues: the 2 lines if `($card[array_keys($card)[$index-1]]['canmove'] != "n")` and  `($card[array_keys($card)[$index+1]]['canmove'] != "n")` should have an else case with something like `$renderedCardFields[$index] = $options['value'];` and the lines where you commented `// if not, just push it to renderedCardFields`, I believe should just use `$index` and not `$index-1` and `$index+1`.  We are still left with the issues when fields can move up or down by more than one field.

Comment: @jSmith I believe I found the right logic, I'll write a new answer for you.

Comment: Thanks Aedix, I had figured something out for myself to fix the issues but my code got much longer than yours. I'll give your code a shot tomorrow and get back to you.

Comment: Awesome! I'll be waiting!

Comment: Hi, seems good -- however the switch case's breaks need "break 2" to break out of both switch and foreach (else it goes to the 30 seconds php timeout). Also it seems like the case when there are more than 1 empty field available to move isn't there (for example go down 3 fields if the below fields are empty and "canmove". Of course the solution I found for my project is based on your answer, so I am marking your answer as correct. Thank you!

Comment: Hey @jSmith, thanks for your return. I didn't understand the `break` problem you faced in my code, if you didn't correct that already please explain better so I can figure it out. As for the "more than one field available", in fact it **is working**, it was just that I didn't outputted any examples of this. I edited my answer so now you can see it in action!

Comment: I can't get it to work -- it seems to enter an infinite loop, maybe related to the $refactor not incrementing somehow

Comment: Ok the issue was `if ($slot+1 > count($cleanCard)) break;`, it worked if I make it if `($slot+1 >= count($cleanCard)) break;` Thanks

Comment: And `if ($slot-1 < 0) break;`  (instead of <=) so that the spot with index 1 can move up to 0. everything's good now, thanks a lot your code is way more concise than the code I have :-)