# PHP multidimensional array sort based on multiple criteria

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

Let us suppose I have an array like below

```
    $item = Array(

             [0] => Array(
                     "name" => "item1"
                     "score" => 100,
                     "category" => "A1",
                     "vote"  => 80,
               )

          [1] => Array(
                 "name" => "item2",
                 "score" => 100,
                 "category" => "A1",
                 "vote"    => 70,
           )
           [2] => Array(
                 "name" => "item3",
                 "score" => 80,
                 "category" => "A2",
                 "vote"    => 80,
           )
           [3] => Array(
                 "name" => "item4",
                 "score" => 80,
                 "category" => "A2",
                 "vote"    => 60,
           )
           [4] => Array(
                 "name" => "item5",
                 "score" => 80,
                 "category" => "A3",
                 "vote"    => 80,
           )
    )
```

edited input:

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => item1
            [score] => 100
            [category] => A1
            [vote] => 80
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => item2
            [score] => 100
            [category] => A1
            [vote] => 80
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => item5
            [score] => 80
            [category] => A3
            [vote] => 80
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [name] => item3
            [score] => 80
            [category] => A2
            [vote] => 80
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [name] => item4
            [score] => 80
            [category] => A2
            [vote] => 60
        )

)
```

The priority of the sort is `score`, `category` and `vote` consequently.
The expected result is :

```
$item = Array(

             [0] => Array(
                     "name" => "item1"
                     "score" => 100,
                     "category" => "A1",
                     "vote"    => 80,
               )
            [1] => Array(
                 "name" => "item5",
                 "score" => 80,
                 "category" => "A3",
                 "vote"    => 80,
            )
            [2] => Array(
                 "name" => "item3",
                 "score" => 80,
                 "category" => "A2",
                 "vote"    => 80,
           )

          [3] => Array(
                 "name" => "item2",
                 "score" => 100,
                 "category" => "A1",
                 "vote"    => 70,
           )

           [4] => Array(
                 "name" => "item4",
                 "score" => 80,
                 "category" => "A2",
                 "vote"    => 60,
           )

    )
```

edited expected result:

```
   Array
    (
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => item1
            [score] => 100
            [category] => A1
            [vote] => 80
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => item5
            [score] => 80
            [category] => A3
            [vote] => 80
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => item3
            [score] => 80
            [category] => A2
            [vote] => 80
        )
   [3] => Array
        (
            [name] => item2
            [score] => 100
            [category] => A1
            [vote] => 80
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [name] => item4
            [score] => 80
            [category] => A2
            [vote] => 60
        )

)
```

I want to have the distinct categories at the top sorted based on the `score` and then `vote` but if they are two items with the same category, the item with the lower score will have lower priority.

Based on the insight from , I first sort the array based on score, category and vote

```
foreach($list as $k=>$v) {
        $sorted['score'][$k] = $v['score'];
        $sorted['category'][$k] = $v['category'];
        $sorted['vote'][$k] = $v['vote'];
    }

    array_multisort($sorted['score'], SORT_DESC, $sorted['category'], SORT_DESC,$sorted['vote'], SORT_DESC, $list);
```

It will give me:

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => item1
            [score] => 100
            [category] => A1
            [vote] => 80
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => item2
            [score] => 100
            [category] => A1
            [vote] => 80
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => item5
            [score] => 80
            [category] => A3
            [vote] => 80
        )



  [3] => Array
        (
            [name] => item3
            [score] => 80
            [category] => A2
            [vote] => 80
        )
    [4] => Array
        (
            [name] => item4
            [score] => 80
            [category] => A2
            [vote] => 60
        )

)
```

I need to re-sort the result again to have the distinct categories at the top (see the edited expected result)

Edited: It seems my example and question are confusing.
The idea is I want to sort the item based on the score and then vote but the category should be taken into consideration. On top of score and vote, I want to have the time with the distinct categories on top and then the score and vote follow.

Comment: You must define a comparison function and use usort() http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24559050/sort-array-using-multiple-criteria-in-php

Comment: I have [answered a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31990237/re-order-an-arrays-items-based-on-several-criteria/31993715#31993715) and my answer was accepted, see if adapting it works for you

Comment: i'm a bit confuse, which is you priority is the score is high but the vote is low?

Comment: the score is preferable that the vote. vote is the second priority. But the category should be taken into consideration.
But on top of that I want to have distinct(different) categories as the priority first then the score and vote follow as mentioned above.

Comment: okay.. i have a suggestion though, why don't you sort them by category first then have a sorting for both votes and scores? and make life a little easier?

Answer (score 1):

use array_multisort()

```
<?php
$mylist = Array(

             0 => Array(
                     "name" => "item1",
                     "score" => 100,
                     "category" => "A1",
                     "vote"  => 80
               ),

          1 => Array(
                 "name" => "item2",
                 "score" => 100,
                 "category" => "A1",
                 "vote"    => 70
           ),
           2 => Array(
                 "name" => "item3",
                 "score" => 80,
                 "category" => "A2",
                 "vote"    => 80
           ),
           3 => Array(
                 "name" => "item4",
                 "score" => 80,
                 "category" => "A2",
                 "vote"    => 60
           ),
           4 => Array(
                 "name" => "item5",
                 "score" => 80,
                 "category" => "A3",
                 "vote"    => 80
           )
    );

$sort = array();
foreach($mylist as $k=>$v) {
    $sort['score'][$k] = $v['score'];
    $sort['category'][$k] = $v['category'];
    $sort['vote'][$k] = $v['vote'];
}
# sort by event_type desc and then title asc
array_multisort($sort['vote'], SORT_DESC,$sort['score'], SORT_DESC, $sort['category'], SORT_DESC,$mylist);
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($mylist);
    echo '</pre>';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: This is not an answer, this is just a suggestion. suppose to be a comment but there are codes and it's quite long.

First i just revamped your input array to this model:

[image]

Using this code:

```
$compiled = array();

for ($i = 0; $i < count($input_arr); $i++)
{
    $cat = $input_arr[$i]['category'];

    $index = count($compiled[$cat]);

    $compiled[$cat][$index]['name'] = $input_arr[$i]['name'];
    $compiled[$cat][$index]['score'] = $input_arr[$i]['score'];
    $compiled[$cat][$index]['vote'] = $input_arr[$i]['vote'];
    $compiled[$cat][$index]['overall'] = $input_arr[$i]['score'] + $input_arr[$i]['vote'];
}
```

I just arranged it by `category`. And also i added `overall` it's just the sum of score and vote. :)

All the sorting comes here:

```
foreach ($compiled as $k => $v)
{
    $json['sorted_by_vote'][$k] = sort_sub_value($compiled[$k], 'vote', false);

    $json['sorted_by_score'][$k] = sort_sub_value($compiled[$k], 'score', false);

    for ($i = 0;$i < count($compiled[$k]); $i++)
    {
        $json['sorted_by_overall'][] = $compiled[$k][$i];
    }
}
$json['sorted_by_overall'] = sort_sub_value($json['sorted_by_overall'], 'overall', false);

$json['input'] = $input_arr;

$json['revamp'] = $compiled;

echo json_encode($json);

function sort_sub_value($array, $subkey, $is_asc = true)
{
    foreach($array as $k=>$v) 
    {
        $b[$k] = strtolower($v[$subkey]);
    }

    if ($is_asc)
        asort($b); // asort -> asc | arsort ->desc
    else
        arsort($b);

    foreach($b as $key=>$val) 
    {
        $c[] = $array[$key];
    }
    return $c;
}
```

and will produce this:

[image]

[image]

[image]

And lastly here's the sample input i just mess with the `votes` to test.

[image]

Hope this would be helpful for some other reason. Cheers brother! :)